# Can I `join` against a command?

Tags: shell, pipe, join

I find `join` pretty useful. It lets you join file1 against file2 on key fields.

Is it possible to do so dynamically against the results of a command, like:

```
join -1 1 -2 1 file1 'curl http://example.com?code=$1&fmt=csv'
```

Maybe using xargs or named pipes?

**Ideally it would do one "lookup" per record/line in file1**

Comment: It's called process substitution: `join file1 <(curl whatever)`

Comment: @don_crissti yes, thanks. I'm looking for something that would do one lookup per input record...edited question

Comment: Please define "one lookup per line". What are you trying to accomplish ? This is definitely a XY question.... you think `join` is the right tool but imo it isn't - you prolly need `grep` or `awk`/`sed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if your shell supports process substitution (`bash` and `ksh93` does) you may do like this:

```
$ join file1 <( yourcommand )
```

This runs the `join` command with `file1` and a file descriptor in `/dev/fd` connected to the standard output of `yourcommand` (which would be your `curl` thingy).

Note that `join` expects all input to be sorted. It requires sorted input streams to be able to parse them only once. In particular, the input needs to be sorted with `sort -b` (ignoring leading blanks).

If that's not the case, you may make it so:

```
$ join <( sort -b file1 ) <( yourcommand | sort -b )
```

Answer (score 2):

If only one of the input files needs to come from a command, a simple pipe is enough. Use `-` as the file name to mean standard input.

```
curl 'http://example.com?code=$1&fmt=csv' | join -1 1 -2 1 file1 -
```

If both files need to come from pipes, then you need something beyond basic shell features. Ksh, bash and zsh have [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution), which allows passing the output of a command anywhere a program expects a file name.

```
curl 'http://example.com?code=$1&fmt=csv' | sort |
join -1 1 -2 1 <(sort file1) -
```

or equivalently for symmetry

```
join -1 1 -2 1 <(<file1 | sort) \
               <(curl 'http://example.com?code=$1&fmt=csv' | sort)
```

Plain sh doesn't have process substitution. A portable solution if you need a command to receive input from multiple pipes is to use named pipes.

```
tmp="$(mktemp -d)"
mkfifo "$tmp/p"
sort <file1 >"$tmp/p" &
curl 'http://example.com?code=$1&fmt=csv' | sort | join -1 1 -2 1 "$tmp/p" -
rm "$tmp/p"
rmdir "$tmp"
```